# HD screenshots for Chrome extensions by Google

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

Google uses very cool SVG-like screenshots for their extensions ([translate](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Y9p-P2ZpQkA4xTnOLBOMnQ9jAVaG6QWMQ6-8a3AbHsA4TjjAEjiuNKbUk8qt9YWFntPHftHVig=s1280-h800-e365), [gmail](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/T_Lsi_42fIjDoLI8tIJwtYhM_-3MfTZwgZSLdCnn2ntuZnNdxl_hT5EcBMltJFkpVNhFI9PO=s1280-h800-e365)). How are they made? Are these screenshots? If not, is there a `*.ai`/`*.svg` template file for these publicly available anywhere? Do you know any non-google extension with such a screenshot (so I can ask the author)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all photoshopped up.

I'm looking in the `chrome.dll` file at the resources and everything is raster in here. For example, this is the downloads button when you press `Ctrl+J` in Chrome.

[image]

Your best option is to try and replicate the UI in Illustrator or Photoshop. It's just two hexagons in a rectangle with round corners and a star and some gradients, not very complicated.

You can also search for [something like this](http://hazelmade.com/projects.html). I know it isn't vector but you know... search the Internet long enough and you'll even find your parents naked.

Comment: You can tell it’s mocked up because the browser action changes its width.

Comment: @JoshLee that's also true but it might be attributed to other reasons, so it's a good practice to look for hard evidence.

Comment: OK, also from the pixels. :-p

Comment: And from seeing quite a few shops in my time. http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/024/183/500pxShopped.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I did some more searching and found no vector files around :/ (nor photos of my naked parents :P ) I guess I'll just need to import bitmap to Illustrator and clean it up.